Как автоматически проверять наличие способов оплат для неавторизованных пользователей на странице checkout (Woocommerce)?
Есть проблема - на сайтах Woocommerce периодически исчезают способы оплаты для неавторизованных пользователей. Соответственно, клиенты не могут оплатить заказ. Проблему вычисляем только тогда, когда поступает жалоба от клиента. Проблему исправляем, но она периодически происходит снова, то на одном сайте, то на другом.
Есть ли какие-то способы автоматической проверки наличия способов оплат для неавторизованных пользователей? Например, как только способы оплат пропали - чтоб сразу сообщалось на почту, телефон или мессенджер?
Заранее спасибо.

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! Мы заметили, что ваш вопрос требует некоторых уточнений. Прежде чем его опубликовать, рекомендуем ознакомиться с справкой о том, как правильно задавать вопросы: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

https://hetrixtools.com/ - позволяет искать текст на странице (способ оплаты) и сообщать результат в телеграм, если страница не работает или искомого текста на ней нет.

Спасибо. А где конкретно на сайте написано, что он ищет текст на странице и сообщает об его отсутствии / неработе страницы?
